# A problem with delete trigger function in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a problem with the **before delete** trigger in PostgreSQL. Talking shortly: it doesn't delete anything.
I have a database for educational purposes which contains among other three tables: **product**, **product_has_image** and **image**. This construction implements many-to-many relationship between **product** and **image** (I will attach a diagram of my database for more context).

My goal is to create an on delete trigger which would delete every image related to a product which I am deleting. I am using **DBeaver** to work with my postgres database and **plpgsql** language for trigger function.

But it doesn't work at all: when I write in sql console `delete from product p where p.id = 105`, nothing happens, DBeaver says 0 rows have been updated, and my later inspection proofs this.
P.S. product with id 105 exists in table products and one image related to it exists in image table. They are also connected with product_has_image table, which I have already checked.
P.P.S product_has_image has ON DELETE CASCEDE rule, so I don't think I can use after delete trigger, because I don't know how to access image table after deleting product.
[Diagram of my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hpV4.png)

I tried to write a standard **before delete** trigger and a trigger function for it using **plpgsql** language.

Here's my code:
**trigger function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.delete_all_similar()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

    begin
        delete from image i where i.id in (select phi.image_id from product_has_image phi where phi.product_id=old.id);
        delete from public.product p where p.id = old.id;
        return old;
    END;
$function$;
```

**trigger:**

```
create trigger delete_all_trigger before
delete
    on
    public.product for each row execute function delete_an_image();
```

P.S. I have already tried to find similar problems on internet and read postgres documentation on similar topics. But I still haven't manage to understand the way this problem could be solved.

Comment: Why don’t you just use a foreign key?

Comment: Please provide the table DDL as inine formatted text and not just an image of the structure. This might have been an oversight, but the trigger is calling `delete_an_image` and not the function that is shown above (`delete_all_similar`).

Comment: You can't delete an `image` because `product_has_image` still have a reference on it. Since this statement fails, an error is thrown and the entire delete statement is rolled-back.

Comment: Do you want to delete all images for a product even when other products might also be associated with those images? Consider following @FrankHeikens' suggestion and use foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE` for each of the columns in the associative table, `product_has_image`.

Comment: By the way, it looks like there is an error in your data model: One image can belong to multiple products. And when that's the case, you don't want to delete the image when one product using this image is deleted. If one image is related to just one product, you should store that information in the table `image`, using a foreign key. And when you have this foreign key in place, you don't need a trigger.

Comment: In your trigger function, delete from `image` only. Don't delete from `product`.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I know that it is not logically correct, I added it because it was necessary to have at least one many-to-many relationship in educational project. You are right, it makes no sense, but I don't think it affects trigger's problem. If it does I will rework it. And this on delete trigger is also a thing I had to add to my project. I mean professor will not be happy until I add this trigger..

Comment: @JohnH yeap that was a case, sorry for a stupid qaustion. Just got home and saw this. Don't know why I havn't seen this problem before. Thank you